# MySQL queries working only on windows but no on linux

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

I have generated a script using Script-Migration and applied the script locally on the database and it worked on MySQL workbench on windows.
But once I tried to apply the same script on a cloned database on a Linux machine it keeps generating the error "Cannot add foreign key".

Edited

```
CREATE TABLE `NoticesOfSchoolReportForms` (
    `Id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `EducationOfficeManagerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `AssignmentNumber` int NOT NULL,
    `Date` DateTime NOT NULL,
    `ModifiedById` varchar(50) NULL,
    `CreatedById` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `ModificationDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `CreatedDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `Deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    `SupervisorId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `SchoolId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_NoticesOfSchoolReportForms` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_NoticesOfSchoolReportForms_Schools_SchoolId` FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolId`) REFERENCES `Schools` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_NoticesOfSchoolReportForms_SuperVisors_SupervisorId` FOREIGN KEY (`SupervisorId`) REFERENCES `SuperVisors` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: That's a code specific error (as opposed to an OS error) please publish script you are running on linux.

Comment: I edited the post and added the script.

Comment: Thanks, need to see the table definitions for schools and supervisors

Comment: A common error when switching to linux are that linux is case sensitive. A table called 'Table' can be queried in windows as 'Table', 'TABLE', 'table' etc. But in linux you need to use the same casing. Not saying this is the case here but it could be. Otherwise you need to show all definitions as mentioned earlier.

Comment: A few hints. Storage Engine: are you using InnoDB ? Import order: are you importing tables in the correct order ? For instance, do tables Schools, SuperVisors already exist ? Collation: do table definitions match on both machines ? Possibly useful command to debug: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`